# Getting an LSI SAS1064e to recognise new drives

Tags: raid, storage, lsi, ibm-xseries

I have an IBM x3200 M3 server running SBS2011. This server has an LSI SAS1063e controller (the basic BR10il RAID controller that comes with that system). Already existing was a RAID1 array of two 500GB SAS drives.

I have inserted two 2TB WD Red drives into the system, with the goal of creating a second RAID1 array for archival storage. This was done while the system was shut down. Upon starting it up and opening the MegaRAID Storage Manager (which is the latest version from the IBM site for this server model) I can see my existing array, as well as one of the new unconfigured drives (but not the second one).

I thought it might be that the drive wasn't fully inserted or something similar, so I pulled that drive out and reinserted it. This didn't help, so I took both of the unconfigured drives out and swapped their positions (the drive that was in bay 3 is now in bay 4, and vice versa). Unfortunately now neither of them are detected by the controller.

What steps do I need to go through in order to get the controller to detect the two new drives that I know are plugged in? I would prefer not to shut the server down, but will if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the drives weren't getting power.

Whilst the drive caddies were fully inserted and clicked into place, they weren't providing the drives with power. I tested by taking the drive out of the caddy and inserting it without a caddy into the bay. It powered on with no problems and was detected almost immediately.

I've made some dodgy modifications to the caddies so they will fit correctly and provide power, as a fix for the short term. Now to do some research into why these caddies weren't the correct ones...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that controller is getting old, do you know what version the firmware is?

I couldn't find any docs for it on the LSI site.  I don't know if it's applicable but I did find this similar problem on IBM site: http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=migr-5075096

```
Update the LSI SAS Controller BIOS and firmware package to version 1.20 or higher.
```

I also found a fujitsu manual for this controller that might help if you haven't got the docs http://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/PRMRGY/b7fy-2311-01en.pdf

I would make sure you have a backup of your 500G RAID1 then try to go into the bios utils to see if those drives are seen and try to set up the second raid in there.